# Erlang: how do I import a module's type declaration?

Tags: erlang

For example, the httpc library (http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#request-4) defines some types:

```
status_line() = {http_version(), status_code(), reason_phrase()}
http_version() = string(), for example, "HTTP/1.1"
status_code() = integer()
reason_phrase() = string()
content_type() = string()
headers() = [header()]
header() = {field(), value()}
```

In my code, I want to write a function that, for example, *consumes* a Result and produces something else. However, `rebar3 dialyzer` complains:

```
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Compiling xxx
===> Compiling src/httpabs.erl failed
src/httpabs.erl:35: type headers() undefined
src/httpabs.erl:35: type status_code() undefined
src/httpabs.erl:35: type status_line() undefined
```

So how do I import those type declarations so I can re-use them?

Answer (score 9):

In general, you use types exported from another module by prefixing the module name, similar to the way you use exported functions: `module:type_name()`.

However, the types you mention are only used in the documentation; they are not actually exported from the `httpc` module.

You can search for `-export_type` directives in the Erlang/OTP source tree; I don't know any other way to know which types are actually exported.

Comment: so if a module does not export it's types (and it appears the httpc source does not https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/inets/src/http_client/httpc.erl) , what is the recommended action for me? Copy and paste their type documentation into my type declarations? How does httpc expect others to use dialyzer if no types are exported? I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: Yes, copy and paste for now — and submit a pull request adding the `-export_type` directive, so the types can be used in a future Erlang release.